# Replace Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-8.1

I have a laptop that came preinstalled with Windows 8.1. I want to replace it with Ubuntu. It doesn't have a DVD drive, so I installed Virtual CloneDrive and mounted the ISO for Ubuntu desktop.

I then restarted my computer, but I got an error from Windows Boot Manager where it looks like it is trying to boot Windows. When I click Enter to go into OS selection, I chose Ubuntu and then I came back to the Windows Boot Manager screen.

I changed the boot order and even tried to disable the Windows Boot Manager, but this made no difference.

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr

  Status: 0xc0000007b

  Info: The application or operating couldn't be loaded because
        a required file is missing or contains errors.
```

Comment: I really don't understand some things here. How could you possibly install Ubuntu on bare metal from a virtual drive in Windows? Why don't you create a usb installation medium for Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry... I am new to this! Thanks for your help, i will create a USB

Comment: @vic: Sorry - I haven't noticed that you commented first.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can't install from virtual drive - [try to prepare Ubuntu USB stick and install from it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick).

Answer (score 0):

From the error that windows boot manager is showing, it seems like you are using Wubi, which [doesn't play well with UEFI](https://answers.launchpad.net/wubi/+question/215339) and at any rate, Wubi is [not supported by Ubuntu anymore](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice).

Moreover, Wubi installs Ubuntu in a file in Windows' C drive instead of creating a partition on the disk, which can cause problems. If installing Ubuntu in its own partition is not an option, I would suggest that you use a virtual machine instead.